# Negative temperature loop

Tags: python, loops

I tried to create a temperature converter with user input, and loop it from 0 to user input temperature. I get it to work for positive temp, but once I put negative Celsius my loop won't work.

```
cels=maxTemp
for cels in range(maxTemp,0,-5):

    calcC = 9.0/5.0 * cels +32
    print("%6.2f |%10.2f" %(cels,calcC))

calcC = 9.0/5.0 * maxTemp +32
print("%6.2f | %10.2f" %(maxTemp,calcC))
```

Result should look like this:

```
Celsius | Fah
--------------
0.00    | 32.00
-5.00   | 23.00
-10.00  | 14.00
```

and so on.

My code only displays one result, not loop. Last 2 lines of code.

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to do. What is the value of `maxTemp` and why do you assign its value to cels then use cels in the `for-loop` ?

Comment: This should work, but these are the worst possible variable names.  Are you really using `calcC` for degrees F?

Answer (score 0):

I mean, in range(), if you want it to go to negative -10, then you have yo use:

```
range(maxTemp,-11,-5)
```

So

```
cels=maxTemp
for cels in range(maxTemp,-11,-5):

    calcC = 9.0/5.0 * cels +32

    print("%6.2f |%10.2f" %(cels,calcC))
```

I hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you normally want your loop to iterate from the maximum value down to zero, but if the maximum is negative, you instead want to loop from zero down to the maximum (which is really the minimum instead, in that case). Your current code doesn't do that. It always loops from the maximum to zero. If the maximum is negative, the range is empty and it doesn't loop at all.

You can fix this by explicitly testing for a negative maximum value and creating the `range` outside the loop:

```
if maxTemp > 0:
    temp_range = range(maxTemp, 0, -5)
else:
    temp_range = range(0, maxTemp, -5)

for cels in temp_range:
    ...
```

Note that you may want to consider changing the range for positive range to be `reversed(range(0, maxTemp, 5))`, as that will make the positive and negative ranges more symmetrical (they won't always include the maximum exactly, only multiples of 5).

Answer (score 0):

cel = 0
            while (cel > maxTemp):

```
            calsC = 9.0/5.0 * cel +32   
            print("%7.2f |%11.2f" %(cel,calsC))
            cel += -5

    calsC = 9.0/5.0 * maxTemp +32
    print("%7.2f | %11.2f" %(maxTemp,calsC))
```